# Augmenting sequence embeddings with multiclass label encodings

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, embedding, transformer-model

I'm using a Transformer to embed windows within a sequence of temporal data. Each data window falls within multiple classes. One of the classes will be the most relevant to interpreting a window, as it influences a signal within the data, but the identity of this class is not known a priori. The number of total classes and the most relevant class can vary between sequences.

I'm looking into ways to adjust the embeddings of windows to relate the windows that share at least one class. This is somewhat analogous to sinusoidal positional encodings, where nearby windows within a sequence have a shorter distance. I've considered using a graph neural network, defining each window as a graph node and drawing edges between windows with the same class. However, I also want the model to potentially be able to recover which windows belong to the 'most relevant class' mentioned above. This means encoding not just that two windows share a class, but also which class they share. I've also looked into multi-hot encoding (where the number of classes would be set to the max possible number of classes), which will then be concatenated/summed with the input. With concatenation, this might drastically increase the input dimensionality. I would appreciate any leads into potential alternatives!